# appending entries to vector in R is producing list instead of vector as expected

Tags: r, vector

I was attempting to fill an empty vector of values using a `for` loop and then reference specific entries from these vectors to fill a data frame. After doing a little researching it appears my vector got converted to a `list`. But I'm not sure how that occurred. The code is pretty simple, unless there is another underlying nuance that I'm missing. Here is the code I used:

```
simul_conf_int_mean_612 = tibble("mean_estimate" = vector(), "lwr" = vector(), "upr" = vector()) #initialized/created an empty data frame

fit_mean_res_612 = vector()
lwr_mean_res_612 = vector()
upr_mean_res_612 = vector()

for (i in 1:5){
  
  fit_mean_res_612[i] = Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612[i,5]
  lwr_mean_res_612[i] = Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612[i,5] - Bonferroni_Grocery_Retailer_mean_612 * sqrt(estimated_var_matrix_mean_response_612[i,i])
  upr_mean_res_612[i] = Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612[i,5] + Bonferroni_Grocery_Retailer_mean_612 * sqrt(estimated_var_matrix_mean_response_612[i,i])
  
}
```

To test if I was doing things in the right way I tested filling a column of my initialized data frame:

```
> simul_conf_int_mean_612[,1] = fit_mean_res_612
Error: Can't recycle `fit_mean_res_612` (size 5) to size 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred
```

This is where the motivation for my whole question came from.

So to see the form of the vector that I created I called it and I got it in the form of a list:

```
> fit_mean_res_612
[[1]]
     [,1]
1 4292.79

[[2]]
      [,1]
2 4245.293

[[3]]
      [,1]
3 4279.424

[[4]]
      [,1]
4 4333.203

[[5]]
      [,1]
5 4917.418
```

Before I get chastised about the inefficiency of writing `for` loops I just read up on it. So I'll "append" that knowledge to further applications. But what am I missing in this simple code?

EDIT: Since the example is so small I'm also able to provide the outputs from`dput` for the variables used in my loop:

```
> dput(head(Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612, 5))
structure(list(Total_Labour_hrs = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cases_Shipped = c(302000, 
245000, 280000, 350000, 295000), Labour_Hrs_Cost = c(7.2, 7.4, 
6.9, 7, 6.7), Holiday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Estimated_mean_response = structure(c(4292.7901491276, 
4245.29336352498, 4279.42418648312, 4333.2032112936, 4917.41807678638
), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), NULL))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(head(estimated_var_matrix_mean_response_612,5))
structure(c(9364732.79459537, 8929134.32888918, 9755196.52837781, 
9778318.18418078, 1361250.54834372, 8929134.3288892, 18113464.4689885, 
11908157.9211221, 1147591.80945451, 862671.162787766, 9755196.52837787, 
11908157.9211222, 12268422.3003328, 8083016.63097916, 4987857.12818105, 
9778318.18418069, 1147591.80945441, 8083016.63097903, 17183253.6748362, 
2100840.51542087, 1361250.54834367, 862671.162787751, 4987857.12818098, 
2100840.51542089, 80202096.5334524), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

Bonferroni is just a constant

```
> Bonferroni_Grocery_Retailer_mean_612
[1] 2.682204
```

I was able to get a working solution by using `unlist`, but now I'm curious as to why my data ended up coercing to a list instead of an atomic vector. It isn't a problem for such a small data set, but I could envision issues when things are scaled up.

EDIT 2:

I've added some code to the initial post to provide an idea of exactly what it is I was attempting to accomplish. I tried just creating a `tibble` after I created the vectors and then filling in the `tibble` then, but it appears that doesn't solve the issue either because the `tibble` ended up looking as follows:

```
> test_conf_bounds = tibble("point_estimate" = fit_pred_613, "lwr" = lwr_pred_613, "upr" = upr_pred_613)
> test_conf_bounds
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  point_estimate    lwr       upr      
  <list>            <list>    <list>   
1 <dbl[,1] [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
2 <dbl[,1] [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
3 <dbl[,1] [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
4 <dbl[,1] [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
```

Comment: You can fix it with `unlist()`. The mode of your vectors is `list`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this when I try this with a sample dataframe. Can you provide a reproducible example ?

Comment: Yea. I'm going to edit the question right now. The site was performing maintenance when I was in the middle of editing.

Comment: check edit just done

Comment: Code perfectly yields a vector, though.

Comment: not an atomic vector. look at the discussion I had below

Comment: Sorry it yields an _atomic_ vector, `num [1:5] 12501 15661 13674 15452 28938`

Comment: I added more context to the question. This also probably falls in line with what I was discussing below with @Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth column of your input data, the `Estimated_mean_response` is a 1-d matrix. So your output is a vector of matrices. Not sure how that happened, but I would just convert that column to a regular numeric column and everything should work as you expect from there.

```r
str(Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612)
#> tibble [5 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ Total_Labour_hrs       : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#>  $ Cases_Shipped          : num [1:5] 302000 245000 280000 350000 295000
#>  $ Labour_Hrs_Cost        : num [1:5] 7.2 7.4 6.9 7 6.7
#>  $ Holiday                : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 1
#>  $ Estimated_mean_response: num [1:5, 1] 4293 4245 4279 4333 4917
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>   .. ..$ : NULL

Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612$Estimated_mean_response <- 
  as.numeric(Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612$Estimated_mean_response)

str(Grocery_Retailer_mean_response_612)
#> tibble [5 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ Total_Labour_hrs       : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#>  $ Cases_Shipped          : num [1:5] 302000 245000 280000 350000 295000
#>  $ Labour_Hrs_Cost        : num [1:5] 7.2 7.4 6.9 7 6.7
#>  $ Holiday                : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 1
#>  $ Estimated_mean_response: num [1:5] 4293 4245 4279 4333 4917
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ah, so I guess I am expecting an `atomic vector` to be displayed. for example if I had written `v =  c(1,1,1,1)` and then called `v`, I would get `1 1 1 1` displayed. That's what I was expecting to occur.  So what would I need to do to get it to become atomic?

Comment: It should be atomic if all the elements you add to it are coercible to the same mode. I can't tell why they wouldn't be from just the code since I can't see the inputs. Could you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by using `dput` to share a small example input which results in a list output when appending?

Comment: You should be able to just do `as.numeric` or `unlist` on the output anyway ... but you should also just use an `apply`-type function so I guess this is more about answering why this happens than how to get an atomic output.

Comment: Yes. I was going to respond to you earlier, but site maintenance ended up happening. I figured out how to get the output, but it involved using `unlist`. So I'm just curious why my output from the `for` loop coerces into a list now.

Comment: @dc3rd We don't know. Your example does yield a numeric vector and not a list. There is something, you are not showing.

Comment: @Roland going over my code again. The only other step I have after all the code above was attempting to fill a column of a table with the values of the vector. What I noticed when I attempted to do that was that the instructions I gave resulted in filling in only the first cell of my table with all 5 components of my vector, which in turn shot me an error. That's where the question initially came from. So perhaps I always did get a numeric vector albeit not in the form I had visualized it happening.

Comment: I'm not sure you are using correct terminology. Possibly by "table" you mean a matrix and by "error" you maybe mean only a warning? I can't comment further without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion and I appreciate you correcting me in terms of using the correct terminology. So to be specific. I was attempting to fill a column of a data frame. My plan was to create the three vectors of values that you see above, then the next step included me initializing an "empty"  `tibble("mean_estimate" = vector(), "lwr" = vector(), "upr" = vector())`, then I was going to fill the `tibble` with the previously created vectors. Perhaps I went astray by creating the `tibble` prior to using it and instead should've just created the `tibble` directly.

Comment: Hopefully the added context allows for a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks. Being able to see the input data revealed the problem. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I know how `Estimated_mean_response` was converted to a matrix....For this particular series of exercises I proceeded to do the raw calculations in the matrix form for linear regressions. So I have broken up the exercises I'm doing into a group of "applying strictly theory" such as doing all the mechanical calculations and then a group of "applying the necessary functions" to get an appreciation of how leveraging the software makes things easier. I had been cognizant of things being in matrix form for previous questions, but this one slipped me.  Thanks for your help.